# Como gravar um arquivo txt com o nome de cada paciente?

Tags: java, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto da faculdade que é um sistema de clinica onde o recepcionista faz o cadastro do paciente e outras mais opções. Estou querendo fazer com que o funcionário cadastre um novo paciente, o formulário seja salvo com o nome do paciente, individualmente. Para cada paciente um novo formulário txt salvo. O codigo que estou fazendo, ele esta salvando somente no arquivo chamado Relatorio, e do jeito que está ele vai sempre sobrepor o anterior. Como faço os cadastros individuais com o nome de cada paciente?:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
String nomeArq="Relatorio.pdf";
int i;
String nome;
String ender;
String email;
String tel;
String bairro;
String numero;
String exame;

File arquivo; 
System.out.printf("Nome do paciente: ");
nome = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Endereço: ");
ender = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Bairro: ");
bairro = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Número: ");
numero = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Telefone: ");
tel = ler.next();
System.out.printf("E-mail: ");
email = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Exame: ");
exame = ler.next();

try
{
  Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq);
  saida.format("          --- Ficha cadastral de pacientes ---");
  saida.format('\n'+"Nome do paciente: "+nome);
  saida.format('\n'+"Endereço: "+ender);
  saida.format('\n'+"Bairro: "+bairro);
  saida.format('\n'+"Numero: "+numero);
  saida.format('\n'+"Email: "+email);
  saida.format('\n'+"Telefone: "+tel);
  saida.format('\n'+"Exame: "+exame);
  saida.close();
    System.out.println("Arquivo '"+nomeArq+"' Salvo com sucesso!");
}
//mostrando erro em caso se nao for possivel gerar arquivo
catch(Exception erro){
  System.out.println("Arquivo nao pode ser gerado!");
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta fala em uma coisa que o código está fazendo errado, mas ele nem isto está fazendo. Seria melhor concluir a parte de gravação do arquivo para depois tentar ver porque está gravando o nome errado, conforme descrito. E a solução é simples: use o nome do paciente como nome do arquivo. É uma solução ingênua, mas funciona e toda arquitetura deste código já é bem ingênuo.

Comment: .txt com o nome do paciente? E se tiver dois pacientes com o mesmo nome? Não seria melhor salvar esses dados em um banco de dados e gerar um relatório a partir dele?

Comment: Galera, o trabalho nao pode ter BD e no caso de ter dois ou mais pacientes com o mesmo nome, a ideia é salvar com o nome e sobrenome do usuario. No codigo acima ele salva o formulario com tdas as informaçoes do usuario porem o nome do arquivo ta Relatorio. Sendo que quero o nome e sobrenome de cada um.  exemplo: Maria Jose.pdf

Comment: Altera a linha `Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq); para Formatter saida = new Formatter(nome +".pdf");` Ou melhor antes dessa linha altere o `nomeArq  = nome +".pdf";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você altera a variável nomeArq com o nome que você quer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
String nomeArq="Relatorio.pdf";
int i;
String nome;
String ender;
String email;
String tel;
String bairro;
String numero;
String exame;

File arquivo; 
System.out.printf("Nome do paciente: ");
nome = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Endereço: ");
ender = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Bairro: ");
bairro = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Número: ");
numero = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Telefone: ");
tel = ler.next();
System.out.printf("E-mail: ");
email = ler.next();
System.out.printf("Exame: ");
exame = ler.next();


nomeArq = nome +".pdf"; // aqui banta altera para o nome que você queira. 

try
{
  Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq);
  saida.format("          --- Ficha cadastral de pacientes ---");
  saida.format('\n'+"Nome do paciente: "+nome);
  saida.format('\n'+"Endereço: "+ender);
  saida.format('\n'+"Bairro: "+bairro);
  saida.format('\n'+"Numero: "+numero);
  saida.format('\n'+"Email: "+email);
  saida.format('\n'+"Telefone: "+tel);
  saida.format('\n'+"Exame: "+exame);
  saida.close();
    System.out.println("Arquivo '"+nomeArq+"' Salvo com sucesso!");
}
//mostrando erro em caso se nao for possivel gerar arquivo
catch(Exception erro){
  System.out.println("Arquivo nao pode ser gerado!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Coloque o código `String nomeArq="Relatorio.pdf";` imediatamente antes do `try`.
Mas já defina o nome que você vai querer, no caso...

```
String nomeArq = "Relatorio-" + nome + ".txt";
try
{
```